# Rectangle to Texture in SDL2 C

Tags: c, sdl

Is it possible to create a Rectangle and somehow turn it into a Texture in SDL2 C?

You can easily load images to textures using the image library but making a simple rectangle seems a lot more complicated.

Comment: [`SDL_RenderDrawRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect) + [`SDL_SetRenderTarget()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget) not working for some reason?

Comment: Do you want your texture to consist only of a single color? Or should the outline of the rectangle have a different color than the fill color?

Comment: I have an SDL_Texture pointer in a struct and I don't want to create an SDL_Rect member and mess up all of the functions + the rectangle must be a single color

Comment: This information appears important. Please [edit] your question to add it. It should not be necessary for someone to read the comments section in order to understand your question.

Comment: This is a problem of your program's design. You should fix the design, rather than wasting memory on single-color textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not meaningful to create a texture in which all pixels are the same color, as that would be a waste of video memory.

If you want to render a single rectangle in a single color without an outline, it would be more efficient to do this directly using the function [`SDL_RenderFillRect`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect).

If you really want to create a texture for a single rectangle in a single color without an outline, then you can create an [`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) with [`SDL_CreateRGBSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface), then use [`SDL_FillRect`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) on that `SDL_Surface` to set the color, and then use [`SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface) to create a [`SDL_Texture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Texture) from that `SDL_Surface`.